# How to batch rename linked files

Tags: batch-rename, batch

I created and linked 50+ files but now they have in the name

```
Link to xyz
```

So what I want is to remove `Link to` from the all 50+ files names

Comment: What do you mean you 'linked' them?

Comment: I pressed right click on a file and pressed make a link. Now I have or a shortcut that if i rename to xyz and remove link to xyz. I can use it as I want it. so can I batch link to from every name ?

Comment: `Linke to` or `**Link to**`? And the `**` are also in the name?

Comment: example **Link to ffmpeg**